# How to change the comment link text "Login or register to post comment" to be shorter eg " comment" in drupal

Tags: drupal

1. I have created a Q&A type using
   **Create Content** in drupal.
2. I have created a new content name
   Ask and Answer.
3. Until this i don't have any issues.
   Now problem is i have enabled
   comments in content type.
4. In this case i need to change the
   "Add new comment" or similar links
   related to comments as "Answer"
   without changing the core comment
   module.
5. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those text are defined in a **[hook_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_link/6)** function. To be able to change them, you'll need to use the **[hook_link_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_link_alter/6)** function

If you're using Drupal 7, links can be modified in **[hook_node_view_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7)**.